# kernel_init marked as __ref

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

While reading through the linux kernel source, I noticed that the `kernel_init` function is annotated with `__ref`.

I understand that the `__ref` annotation is to prevent modpost warnings when data/code annotated as `__init` are referenced. In this specific case, `kernel_init` calls `kernel_init_freeable` which is marked `__init`.  Why is `kernel_init` not marked with the `__init` annotation itself?

Answer (score 0):

Code marked __init is placed into separate section that is "freed" (which means, memory occupied by it is put into free lists to be used later for other purposes) after kernel initialization completes.

This physically is done by free_initmem() that is called from kernel_init().
Thus marking kernel_init() will cause it to be freed before it's execution completes.